# Benefits of having several several IPs on the same computer

Tags: networking, ip

What is the benefit/use of having several IP addresses on the same computer whether it's a client or a server?

Answer (score 2):

If you were hosting websites, for example, you could host one per IP, instead of having both sites on the same IP, switching in your web server.  In general, it provides one level of isolation which always helps to...well...isolate one system from another.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with test environments where we need multiple instances of the same application running on the same server, each acting as as its own test environment.
By using distinct IP addresses, it was easy to tweak the address that each instance binds to, and this also helped to keep the configuration fairly consistent across the environments.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "having several IP addresses", but if mean having them on a server, it would for example allow you to assign different IP addresses to different websites/FTP sites etc. It helps to build a better, separated system.

Plus, for example, when you do HTTPS/SSL, you will most likely need a dedicated IP address for each such domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways a computer may have several IPs:

- Several IPs on the same network interface: the computer hosts services associated with different IP addresses, for example several websites. Note however that several websites, each having its domain name, may share the same IP, with the “[virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)” mechanism.
- Several network interfaces, each having an IP address within a given network: then the computer serves different purposes on different networks, and may act as a *router* across several networks.